# Java reuse java classes in Android

Tags: java, android, class, reusability

I was wondering if it is possible to uje some classes I made with J2ME with android projects?
For example I have class that gets ip as parameter and scans open ports for that ip using java sockets and threads. So can I use it with my android projects without modifying it?

Comment: Unless you have something specific J2ME API, it should be fine to use those classes.

Answer (score 1):

The Android J2ME runner allows existing J2ME applications to run on the Android platform. You shouldnt need to modify your source either. See [here](http://www.renjusblog.com/2010/09/install-jar-files-android-j2me-runner.html) for more info.